# Remove all qoutes from a string iOS Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

I've seen solutions for objective-c but not for swift.  I'm new to iOS development, any help would greatly be appreciated

I want to remove all " from this string:

```
 let test:NSString = jsonData.valueForKey("test") as! NSString
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(_:withString)` will do the trick:

```
let myString = "\"test\""
let noQuotes = myString.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString( "\"", withString: "" )
```